# convert values of list of dictionaries with different keys to new list of dicts

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have this list of dicts:

```py
[{'name': 'aly', 'age': '104'}, 
 {'name': 'Not A name', 'age': '99'}]
```

I want the name value to be the key and the age value to be the value of new dict.

Expected output:

```py
['aly' : '104', 'Not A name': '99']
```

Comment: Your expected output is not valid python. Do you want `{'aly' : '104', 'Not A name': '99'}` or `[{'aly' : '104', 'Not A name': '99'}]`?

Comment: Or `[{'aly': '104'}, {'Not A name': '99'}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initialize the new dict, iterate through the list and add to the new dict:

```
lst = [{'name': 'aly', 'age': '104'}, {'name': 'Not A name', 'age': '99'}]

newdict = {}
for item in lst:
  newdict[item['name']] = item['age']
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want output to be single dict, you can use dict comprehension:

```py
output = {p["name"]: p["age"] for p in persons}
>>> {'aly': '104', 'Not A name': '99'}
```

If you want output to be list of dicts, you can use list comprehension:

```py
output = [{p["name"]: p["age"]} for p in persons]
>>> [{'aly': '104'}, {'Not A name': '99'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you:

```
d = [
 {'name': 'aly', 'age': '104'}, 
 {'name': 'Not A name', 'age': '99'}
]
dict([i.values() for i in d])
# Result
{'aly': '104', 'Not A name': '99'}

# In case if you want a list of dictionary, use this
[dict([i.values() for i in d])]
# Result
[{'aly': '104', 'Not A name': '99'}]
```

Just a side note:
Your expected answer looks like a list (because of [ ]) but values inside the list are dictionary (key:value) which is invalid.

Comment: "To new list of dicts" implies that OP wants `[{'aly': '104'}, {'Not A name': '99'}]`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the easiest way to convert the new list of dicts

```
res = list(map(lambda data: {data['name']: data['age']}, d))
print(res)
```